# trying to create pList however its not being created

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

I have set up a object class that I am using to create my pList however I am having some issues with it. I am using the singleton design pattern on the class so I only have to deal with one instance of it at any one time...

for some weird reason it has stopped working properly and for the life of me I cannot figure out why, I am woundering if it has something to do with it being in a singleton design pattern..

```
#pragma mark Singleton Methods
+ (id)sharedManager {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedMyManager == nil)
            sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedMyManager;
}
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        // get paths from root direcory (where we will store and fine our plist in the future)
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        // get documents path
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        // get the path to our plist file
        NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"EngineProperties.plist"];

        NSLog(@"pList path = %@", plistPath);

        // check to see if .plist exists in documents
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
        {
            // if not in documents, get property list from main bundle
            plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EngineProperties" ofType:@"plist"];

        }

        // read property list into memory as an NSData object
        NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
        NSString *errorDesc = nil;
        NSPropertyListFormat format;
        // convert static plist into dictionary object (this is where any saved values get put into 
        savedEnginePropertiesDict = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];

        //Load all current values of the property list thats been put into savedEnginePropertiesDict into their variables
            if (savedEnginePropertiesDict && [savedEnginePropertiesDict count]){
                // assign values
                self.sig = [savedEnginePropertiesDict objectForKey:@"Signature"];
                self.ver = [savedEnginePropertiesDict objectForKey:@"Version"];
                self.num = [savedEnginePropertiesDict objectForKey:@"Number"];
                self.dataV = [savedEnginePropertiesDict objectForKey:@"Data"];
                self.cache = [savedEnginePropertiesDict objectForKey:@"Cache"];

        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

This should be creating the directory where the plist should reside, then if its there reading it, else creating it.. but its not doing any of that.. and I am at a complete loss as to figuring out why its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setting the values, but not writing to file.

```
[savedEnginePropertiesDict writeToFile: plistPath atomically: YES];
```

Comment: damn, that didn't seem to work either... I even tried deleting the app from the simulator and rebuilding it so it saved into a new bundle but that didn't help either.